# How do i clear a user input and use the same variabel again?

Tags: vb.net, loops, input

Sorry if the question is not clear. I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a small JARVIS-like program for fun. I'm coding this in vb.net since that's the only language I have been taught in school. This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim txtInput As String

    txtInput = Console.ReadLine()

    Select Case txtInput
        Case Is = "hello jarvis", "hello"
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Sir")

        Case Is = "jarvis"
            Console.WriteLine("Yes Sir")
    End Select

        Select txtInput
        Case Is = "what time is it", "what's the time", "current time"

    End Select

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

End Module

I'm trying to make it so that I can keep asking it different case questions and will be give a different response each time. Right now, I can only ask it one question and it will give me one output. This probably has a simple answer but as I said, I literally just started programming a 2-3 weeks ago.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a loop to read new input into `txtInput` until something like "Quit" is enetered

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the user's input do either:

```
TextBox1.Text = ""
```

Or if you want to remove a variable's value:

```
Variable = ""
```